# Calling layer.setNeedsDisplay() shows a black background

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, calayer

When I call `setNeedsDisplay()` on my UIView's CALayer (either directly, or via `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange`), it draws the background as black.

```
myView.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
```

When I call 'setNeedsDisplay()' on the UIView directly, it doesn't show up as black:

```
myView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that my view's background color was somehow set to `nil` instead of `.white` or `.clear`, for example.

It seems odd that this happens only when calling it on the layer and not the view.

To reproduce...

This shows up as white:

```
myView.backgroundColor = nil
myView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

This causes the view to display as black:

```
myView.backgroundColor = nil
myView.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
```